# How can I prove that $a\implies b$ equals $\neg b\implies\neg a$ with truth tables?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How can I prove that $a\implies b$ equals $\neg b\implies\neg a$ with truth tables?

I've made a separate truth table for each but I am unsure on how to make it into a single/combined truth table..[image]

EDIT: would this then be the correct way to prove it?
Suggestion 1:
[image]

Suggestion 2:
[image]

Comment: Sorry, thats what I need help with

Comment: Your $\neg a$ and $\neg b$ columns are incorrect.

Comment: You can use logical equivalence.  Or you might circle the relevant two columns in the truth table for suggestion 2.

Answer (score 5):

You can't compare two statements unless you put them in the *same* truth table. So you should put your tables together in one big table of six columns and four rows so that the $a$ and $\lnot a$ columns correspond correctly, and same for $b$ and $\lnot b$, then compare the $a\to b$ and $\lnot b\to\lnot a$ columns.

Comment: I edited the post and added a photo of how I tried to do it. Does it look correct the way I did it now? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Angelica33 The second suggestion is correct. In the first suggestion you have both $a$ and $\lnot a$ being $T$ in the first row, which cannot be.

Answer (score 1):

For all values of a,b you have shown the two expressions have the same value.  Thus the two are logically equivalent.  If you do not understand why, then make a truth table for
(a implies b) iff (not b implies not a).

It will tell you the same thing, that the two expressions have the same value for all choices of a,b.